# Manga where the MC lives a slow life with a demon general

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character tries out a skill and accidentally kills all the demons in the forest. The main character meets a demon general, which is a Fenrir, and the demon general falls in love with the main character and follows him.

Answer (score 10):

Could this be *[Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Super Cheat Powers](https://myanimelist.net/manga/119152/Lv2_kara_Cheat_datta_Motoyuusha_Kouho_no_Mattari_Isekai_Life) (Lv2 kara Cheat datta Motoyuusha Kouho no Mattari Isekai Life)*?

> Banaza, who got summoned to the magic kingdom of Cryroad as a Hero
> candidate, due to having only the abilities of only a regular citizen,
> got treated as a disqualified Hero. He, who originally was supposed to
> be returned to his original world, due to the magic kingdom's mistake,
> became unable to return to his original world, inevitably has to live
> in this world. That kind of person, the moment he became Lv2, acquired
> all skills and magics, and transcended into a super cheat with all
> ability points broken through the limit! Even so, he does things at
> his own pace with an easygoing smile.

- At the end of Episode 1 he uses a spell to sanctify a forest and it blankets half the continent.
- At the end of Episode 2, the girl that he was guarding turns out to be a magical demon king (in the form of a 'Fengal' wolf named Fenris)
- In Episode 3, he fights and defeats her in her demonic form and she offers to marry him.

[image]